# How to display local time zone?

Tags: angularjs, date

I am using `datetimepicker.js`.

I have the following code:

**Partial HTML:**

```
<div ng-hide="editingData[x.date]">{{x.date|date}} </div>
```

So my date is coming as:

```
May 21, 2015 2:52:29 PM
```

**Expected:**

```
May 21, 2015 2:52:29 PM IST
```

So Is there any easy way to add timezone in `angularjs` ?

I am having `moment.js` included as well and found that it can manipulate dates well. Can it be helpful ?

Comment: Try     date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm Z'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displaying local time zone

may be this will help you :)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{date | date:'MMM dd yyyy - h:mm:ss a '}} {{z}}

</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();

    var now = new Date().toString();
    $scope.z = now.indexOf('(') > -1 ?
    now.match(/\([^\)]+\)/)[0].match(/[A-Z]/g).join('') :
    now.match(/[A-Z]{3,4}/)[0];
    if ($scope.z == "GMT" && /(GMT\W*\d{4})/.test(now)) {
       $scope.z = RegExp.$1;}
}
```

[Working js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BijayRai/xoxo62qv/2/)